# call another application from non activity class

Tags: android

I want to call another application from one.My call to another application is from non activity class.but the `getPackageManager()` shows the error like this `The method getPackageManager() is undefined for the type AppLauncher`. I imported the package manager also,still it shows the same error.

Is it possible to call another app from non activity class?thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Pass your `activity context` to `non-activity class`. And from that context call the different application.

Answer (score 1):

You need a context to call `getPackageManager()` on it. Get the context from an activity in your app:

in onCreate block of your main activity:

```
AppLauncher.setContext(this.getBaseContext));
```

in your Non-Activity Class (AppLauncher):

```
Context context;
public static void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

in your Non-Activity Class where you want to call getPackageManager():

```
context.getPackageManager();
```

**Tip**: if you are developing in eclipse on windows, always use Ctrl+Shift+O to automatically import missing and required packages.

Comment: @SURESHKUMAR nice! then you may want to accept an answer, so other users can find which answer was best for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Those methods (such as *getPackageManager()* or *startActivity()*) are members of a context.
You need to pass either your main activity or its Context to the other class.

BTW I don't get why you need package manager to launch another application. What about calling startActivity() with the corresponding intent ?
(but I guess there are good reasons for doing it your way)